# Java, возврат имени объекта.

Tags: java

День добрый, подскажите как можно вернуть имя объекта? Например, есть 2 объекта:

```
Point obj1 = new Point();
Point obj2 = new Point();
```

Чтоб в строке возвращалось имя объекта:

```
void NameReturn(Point object){
  System.out.print("Object name : " + object); 
}
```

Comment: А что такое имя объекта? Если имя переменной, которая хранит ссылку на него, то никак?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Point obj1 = new Point("obj1");
Point obj2 = new Point("obj2");
...
class Point{
  String name = "";

  public Point(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String toString(){
    return name;
  }
}
```

Больше вариантов нет.

Answer (score 0):

Унаследуйте класс, добавьте в него поле типа String, переопределите метод toString()